# Yeoman Documentation - appendScripts?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, yeoman

Is there documentation anywhere for some of the scripts used for Angular generators?  For instance, `appendScripts()` or `extraModules()` found in generator-angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generator documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/wiki/base#wiringappendscripts)

Answer (score 2):

The Yeoman API is now available here: http://yeoman.github.io/generator/

Documentation for appendScripts specifically can be found in the wiring section: http://yeoman.github.io/generator/wiring.html

Answer (score 0):

@Sindre Sorhus' answer is outdated while @Jason's should be marked as the correct one.